# Wanted - better Flash Professional tools

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Can anyone recommend a plugin/extension for Flash Professional that can improve debugging features for Flash Professional. Currently, I'm using FlashDevelop to assist with coding tasks, but breakpoints etc. don't yet work well with FLA based projects.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, one possibility is to do the majority of your development with FlashDevelop, FDT or FlexBuilder (soon to be called FlashBuilder) and have your output be a SWC. Flash CS4 can now compile in SWCs - it's in the publish settings under ActionScript settings.

We build the majority of our Flash projects in this manner or sort of in reverse where we build the assets in Flash Professional, output a SWC of the graphics and use that SWC in a better development environment (we prefer FDT).

Comment: I'll take a peek into FDT. Sounds like the most logical thing to export assets as SWC's. I just hate when people code on the Flash Professional timeline.